# test if a string starts with a number

Tags: c++, regex

I'm just starting to learn C++. What are my options for testing if a string starts with a number? My function `is_page_number` does the trick (I think) in the following program. Is this a bad idea? How can I use a regex here? If any part of the code is not well-written, any comment is appreciated.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::ifstream;
using std::endl;

bool is_page_number(const string& aline) {
    return aline[0] == '1' | aline[0] == '2' | aline[0] == '3' | aline[0] == '4' | aline[0] == '5' | aline[0] == '6' | aline[0] == '7' | aline[0] == '8' | aline[0] == '9';
}

int main() {
    const string temp_filename("test_input.txt");
    ifstream input(temp_filename.c_str());
    string one_line;
    while (getline(input,one_line)) {
            if(is_page_number(one_line)) {
                    cout << "page number: ";
            }
            cout << one_line << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isdigit/

Comment: Don't use the bitwise or operator | when you really mean a logical or ||.  Also, think about what happens if is_page_number receives an empty string.  Likewise, what happens if the string starts with 0?  I already see an answer pointing you to the correct function in cctype, but ponder these other points too.

Comment: @nsanders, if it starts with 0, then it's octal page number! ;-)

Comment: @nsanders great points to think about. Thank you for these! I guess is_page_number could receive an empty string only if one_line is an empty string (is this a fair assumption or can I not even assume that?). So I would need to check that one_line is not empty or see what happens when it is.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker 03 may be octal.  But 0 is just zero.  Though since these are page numbers, explicitly forbidding zero might be correct.

Comment: @XuWang How you want to handle the error condition is up to you.  In general you want to avoid going out of array bounds in any event.  From a defensive programming perspective, at a minimum consider a simple assert( !aline.empty() ).

Comment: @nsanders ok, that sounds like a good approach. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <cctype>

return isdigit(aline[0]);
```

Comment: Here is some documentation for this function: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isdigit/